# GitHub Desktop - Cannot Upload/Update Projects Because of Unknown User

Tags: git, github, project, account

#### Description

Uploading/Updating Projects using GitHub Desktop is so easy before, now it just stops,
Due to this huge bug that is happening.

#### Version

**GitHub Desktop version:** 1.0.12
**OS version:** Windows 10

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Launch GitHub Desktop Normally
2. Upload/Update Any Project
3. Get Error

**Expected behavior:** Upload/Update Project

**Actual behavior:** Error saying: "

```
Commit failed - exit code 128 received, 
Please tell me who you are.
```

**Reproduces how often:** Always

#### Logs

```
2018-01-14T05:50:48.279Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 1 repositories from store
2018-01-14T05:50:48.295Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account:  GitHub Name (Full Name)
2018-01-14T05:50:50.742Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.0.12 (Windows 10.0.15063)
2018-01-14T05:50:50.749Z - info: [ui] Executing getStatus: git status --untracked-files=all --branch --porcelain=2 -z (took 2.494s)
2018-01-14T05:50:50.765Z - info: [ui] Executing getBranches: git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(refname:short)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(author)%00%(parent)%00%(symref)%00%(subject)%00%(body)%00%1F refs/heads refs/remotes (took 2.318s)
2018-01-14T05:50:50.766Z - info: [ui] Executing getRecentBranches: git log -g --no-abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline HEAD -n 2500 -- (took 2.290s)
2018-01-14T05:50:53.624Z - info: [ui] Executing getAuthorIdentity: git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT (took 1.962s)
2018-01-14T05:50:54.672Z - info: [ui] Executing installGlobalLFSFilter: git lfs install --skip-repo (took 4.525s)
2018-01-14T05:51:04.622Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 3.461s)
2018-01-14T05:56:15.470Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.420s)
2018-01-14T06:01:25.864Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.381s)
2018-01-14T06:06:36.464Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.555s)
2018-01-14T06:11:50.576Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 4.717s)
2018-01-14T06:15:19.466Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] loading 1 repositories from store
2018-01-14T06:15:19.469Z - info: [ui] [AppStore] found account: GitHub Name (Full Name)
2018-01-14T06:15:20.585Z - info: [ui] launching: 1.0.12 (Windows 10.0.15063)
2018-01-14T06:15:20.586Z - info: [ui] Executing getStatus: git status --untracked-files=all --branch --porcelain=2 -z (took 1.121s)
2018-01-14T06:15:21.700Z - info: [ui] Executing installGlobalLFSFilter: git lfs install --skip-repo (took 1.809s)
2018-01-14T06:15:51.704Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 2.835s)
2018-01-14T06:21:00.310Z - info: [ui] Executing getBranches: git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(refname:short)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(author)%00%(parent)%00%(symref)%00%(subject)%00%(body)%00%1F refs/heads refs/remotes (took 1.480s)
2018-01-14T06:21:00.310Z - info: [ui] Executing getRecentBranches: git log -g --no-abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline HEAD -n 2500 -- (took 1.461s)
2018-01-14T06:21:00.331Z - info: [ui] Executing getStatus: git status --untracked-files=all --branch --porcelain=2 -z (took 2.076s)
2018-01-14T06:21:21.829Z - info: [ui] Executing fetch: git -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --prune origin (took 1.802s)
2018-01-14T06:21:24.623Z - info: [ui] Executing updateIndex: git update-index --add --remove --replace -z --stdin (took 2.662s)
2018-01-14T06:21:25.955Z - info: [ui] Executing createCommit: git commit -F - (took 1.331s)
2018-01-14T06:21:25.958Z - error: [ui] `git commit -F -` exited with an unexpected code: 128.

    Please tell me who you are

Run

  `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`<br />
  `git config --global user.name "Your Name"`<br />

to set your account's default identity.   
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Name@AccountName.(none)')

2018-01-14T06:22:03.119Z - info: [ui] Executing getStatus: git status --untracked-files=all --branch --porcelain=2 -z (took 20.402s)
2018-01-14T06:22:03.345Z - info: [ui] Executing getBranches: git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(refname:short)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(author)%00%(parent)%00%(symref)%00%(subject)%00%(body)%00%1F refs/heads refs/remotes (took 20.546s)
2018-01-14T06:22:03.346Z - info: [ui] Executing getRecentBranches: git log -g --no-abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline HEAD -n 2500 -- (took 16.309s)
```

### Additional Information

Using `git config --global user.email "you@example.com"` don't even work, Command Prompt even says:

```
'git' is not recognized as a internal or external program.
```

Even reinstalling doesn't even work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should type, using your GitHub account email (and any name you want):

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

But if Git is not recognized, uncompress the latest [Git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), which is [`PortableGit-2.15.1.2-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.15.1.windows.2/PortableGit-2.15.1.2-64-bit.7z.exe) and add it to your PATH (as [I do here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47826648/6309)).

Comment: It worked, but you need to run the git-cmd.exe file to run it, but I'll put it in the Start Menu.

Comment: Then I tried that, and it worked, sort of. It said `Committing as Name <email>`. But it was committed!

Comment: Wrong Email Set in `user.email`, my bad!